# Wordpress drop-down menu always open on the iPad

Tags: ipad, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I use the template Citizen Journal.
I don't know if it's just for this template but there is a quiet annoying problem.

The top menu doesn't appear correctly on the iPad.

I uploaded screenshot from the Desktop and the second on the iPad here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1aU4.jpg

You can see that the menu becomes a drop-down menu that is always open.
It blocks the view of the different pages, that is really annoying.

You can test it if you have an iPad:
http://www.professorparticular.org/

I've search a lot for a solution but nothing close to what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear the theme you are using is a responsive theme and changes the content dimensions based on screen size/resolution.  It will remove and or move some elements on the page when you view the site on a device with a smaller screen.

One quick fix for this is to go to the header.php file in the theme's files and remove the 5th line from the top.  The line to remove is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`.  This should fix your menu problem.  Without actually going into the CSS and HTML of the theme and recoding it, this is probably your easiest option.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer.

I never though of that, I though it was a glitch or something.
Finally I went into the CSS and commented all that is related of menu modification if the size changed.
Now the widgets still goes on the bottom (good as screen smaller) but the menu buttons bo under each others.
It's not perfectly nice but it is navigable way better than before.

Once again, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You're very welcome.  You can also give the width in that meta tag a set number of pixels.  Just like in CSS you use 960px or any number followed by px.  You can play with that some and see if that helps at all.  Please pass a vote up for me as well if my suggestions helped you!

Comment: I'd like to up vote but I dont have enough reputation..
Please, do it everyone else! :-)